# Filtering values of a listbox in javascript by value of another listbox

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, listbox

I am trying to retain the value (URL) of **selectbox1** when filtering what is shown in **selectbox1** by selecting a value in **selectbox0**. It is being filtered against **selectbox2**.

The issue I am having is that it is not the URL (value) is not retained, only the inner text is kept in **selectbox1** after I filter it.

Another thing that I would like to solve is that I would like to make **selectbox2** hidden from the user, if possible.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Links</title>
    <select id="selectbox0" name="" ;>
        <option value="" selected>All</option>
        <option value="Google">Google</option>
        <option value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selectbox1" name="" ;>
        <option value="https://www.google.com" selected>Google</option>
        <option value="https://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</option>
        <option value="https://www.apple.com">Apple</option>
    </select>
        <select id="selectbox2" name="" ;>
        <option value="https://www.google.com" selected>Google</option>
        <option value="https://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</option>
        <option value="https://www.apple.com">Apple</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="openInTabSelect();">Open</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openInTabSelect() {
            var pSelect = document.getElementById('selectbox1').value;
            //console.log(pSelect)
            var newTab = safari.self.browserWindow.openTab();
            newTab.url = pSelect;
        }

        var selectbox0 = document.getElementById('selectbox0'),
        selectbox1 = document.getElementById('selectbox1'),
        selectbox2 = document.getElementById('selectbox2');

        selectbox0.addEventListener('change', function() {
            selectbox1.innerHTML = '';
            for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < selectbox2.children.length; childIndex++) {
                var child = selectbox2.children[childIndex];
                if (child.innerHTML.search(selectbox0.value) != -1) {
                    option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.innerHTML = child.innerHTML;
                    selectbox1.appendChild(option);
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Expected: Selecting **Google** in **selectbox0** should filter out and only show **Google** in **selectbox1** and retain its value **www.google.com** which will be used to open in a new tab by clicking on button **Open**.

Exp. element: `< option value="https://www.google.com" selected="">Google< /option >`

Actual: Selecting **Google** in **selectbox0** does filter out and only show **Google** in **selectbox1** but does not retain its value **www.google.com**.

Act. element: `< option >Google< /option >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found your problem. You are using `innerHTML` to get a value, but you want the value. `innerHTML` gets the text in your option field, not the value. Try this:

```
if (child.search(selectbox1.value) != -1) {
   option = document.createElement('option');
   option.innerHTML = child.innerHTML;
   selectbox1.appendChild(option);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Xavier, that seems to be the issue! :)

Would you know how I might hide selectbox2? (or any element for that matter) from the user.

Comment: @Joe Berg I was suspect of what you described in your answer as well. but have to tackle one thing at a time.

Comment: @Joe Berg Do you mean to hide the HTML element from displaying on the webpage? And are you trying to hide it with javascript or CSS? It easy with CSS, just add a property like this `display:none;`. This really is a separate question though.

Comment: @Joe Berg if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Xavier, and thanks for the quick input for hiding element with CSS, it also worked great! :)

    <style>
    select[id="selectbox2"]{
    display:none;
    }
    </style>

Comment: @Joe Berg You are welcome. You can also use javascript too `element.style.display = "none" ;`

Answer (score 0):

Your `.getElementById()` statement points to an id that does not exist `selectbox`:

```
var pSelect = document.getElementById('selectbox').value;
```

I'm not quite sure which id you were intending to point to, but try clearing this up first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have renamed it to selectbox1 now. A mistake when I pasted the code here in the question. I renamed them selectbox0, 1 and 2 for stackoverflow hoping it would be easier to read the code.


pSelect should give me the value (URL) of selectbox1, e.g. google.com, microsoft.com or apple.com depending on the selection of selectbox0.

Comment: @Joe Berg you are calling a variable that does not exist as well `selectboxX`

Comment: Sorry about that was well Xavier, selectboxX should be selectbox0. I really should have paid more attention to my variables when I posted the code.

Comment: @Joe Berg no worries :) glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for reading this, but I managed to figure it out myself. I am sorry for asking the question a bit prematurely. By adding a second line where I defined the value of option first it worked.

```
            option.value = child.value;
            option.innerHTML = child.innerHTML;
```